# How to find closest elements in two array without repetitions [duplicated] and return the indexs of two array in Python?

Tags: python

I have 2 arrays list1 and list2

```
list1= np.array([0.        , 0.09705882, 0.19411765, 0.29117647, 0.38823529,
       0.48529412, 0.58235294, 0.67941176, 0.77647059, 0.87352941,
       0.97058824, 1.06764706, 1.16470588, 1.26176471, 1.35882353,
       1.45588235, 1.55294118, 1.65      , 1.74705882, 1.84411765,
       1.94117647, 2.03823529, 2.13529412, 2.23235294, 2.32941176,
       2.42647059, 2.52352941, 2.62058824, 2.71764706, 2.81470588,
       2.91176471, 3.00882353, 3.10588235, 3.20294118, 3.3       ,
       3.39705882, 3.49411765, 3.59117647, 3.68823529, 3.78529412,
       3.88235294, 3.97941176, 4.07647059, 4.17352941, 4.27058824,
       4.36764706, 4.46470588, 4.56176471, 4.65882353, 4.75588235,
       4.85294118, 4.95      , 5.04705882, 5.14411765, 5.24117647,
       5.33823529, 5.43529412, 5.53235294, 5.62941176, 5.72647059,
       5.82352941, 5.92058824, 6.01764706, 6.11470588, 6.21176471,
       6.30882353, 6.40588235, 6.50294118, 6.6       ])
list2=np.array([3.3 , 3.2 , 3.1 , 3.  , 2.9 , 2.8 , 2.7 , 2.6 , 2.5 , 2.4 , 2.3 ,
       2.2 , 2.1 , 2.  , 1.9 , 1.8 , 1.7 , 1.6 , 1.5 , 1.4 , 1.3 , 1.2 ,
       1.1 , 1.05, 0.95, 0.85, 0.75, 0.7 , 0.6 , 0.5 , 0.4 , 0.3 , 0.2 ,
       0.1 , 0])
```

for each element in a I would like to find the closest element in b and return the index of both of them

```
list2aux = list(list2)
mylist = []
for idxlabel in range(0,len(list1)): 
    a = min(enumerate(list2aux), key=lambda x:abs(x[1]-list1[idxlabel]))
    list2aux[a[0]] = 0
    print(a)
    mylist.append(np.copy(a))
```

My problem is that after that one element in list2 is found as "best match" I would like to print the index of both elements in arrays whose values are close together also I would like to remove it from the search to avoid that different element in list1 match with the same element in list2

```
(34, 0.0)
(33, 0.1)
(32, 0.2)
(31, 0.3)
(30, 0.4)
(29, 0.5)
(28, 0.6)
(27, 0.7)
(26, 0.75)
(25, 0.85)
(24, 0.95)
(23, 1.05)
(21, 1.2)
(20, 1.3)
(19, 1.4)
(18, 1.5)
(17, 1.6)
(16, 1.7)
(15, 1.8)
(14, 1.9)
(13, 2.0)
(12, 2.1)
(11, 2.2)
(10, 2.3)
(9, 2.4)
(8, 2.5)
(7, 2.6)
(6, 2.7)
(5, 2.8)
(4, 2.9)
(3, 3.0)
(2, 3.1)
(1, 3.2)
(0, 3.3)
(22, 1.1)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
```

in this example Zero value is repeated !!! And the index of one of the array is displayed if I need the index of both elements in arrays whose values are close together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where()` to get indexes of matched elements in numpy arrays.

Given the two lists above, you can try this following code (without removing elements from list2 after found):

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):

  temp_result = abs(list1[i] - list2) #Matrix subtraction

  min_val = np.amin(temp_result) #Getting the minimum value to get closest element
  min_val_index = np.where(temp_result == min_val) #To find index of minimum value

  closest_element = list2[min_val_index] #Actual value of closest element in list2

  print(i, list1[i], min_val_index[0][0], closest_element[0])
```

---

Removing elements as soon as they are found in list2, eventually, list2 will be empty so to avoid any runtime errors the safety check is present.

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):

  if (len(list2)) > 1: #When there are elements in list2

    temp_result = abs(list1[i] - list2) #Matrix subtraction

    min_val = np.amin(temp_result) #Getting the minimum value to get closest element
    min_val_index = np.where(temp_result == min_val) #To find index of minimum value

    closest_element = list2[min_val_index] #Actual value of closest element in list2

    list2 = list2[list2 != closest_element] #Remove closest element after found

    print(i, list1[i], min_val_index[0][0], closest_element[0]) #List1 Index, Element to find, List2 Index, Closest Element

  else: #All elements are already found

    print(i, list1[i], 'No further closest unique closest elements found in list2')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Can you help continue this code at the following link? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58682961/11730789

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `enumerate()` here. Instead, you can iterate over `list1` and find the closest element of `list2` using a simpler `min()` call.

In order to prevent duplicate matches in `list2`, you can remove each element from `list2` as you find it. Numpy arrays are immutable, which makes this a little more complex. Here's an example assuming ordinary python lists, allowing you to use the standard `remove()` method.

```
# iterate by value
for list1_val in list1:
  # stop when list2 is empty
  if len(list2) == 0:
      break
  # find the closest match
  list2_val = min(list2, key=lambda x:abs(x-list1_val))
  # print the value pair
  print(list1_val, ',', list2_val)
  # remove the match from list2
  list2.remove(list2_val)
```

This yields the result:

```
0.0 , 0
0.09705882 , 0.1
0.19411765 , 0.2
0.29117647 , 0.3
0.38823529 , 0.4
0.48529412 , 0.5
0.58235294 , 0.6
0.67941176 , 0.7
0.77647059 , 0.75
0.87352941 , 0.85
0.97058824 , 0.95
1.06764706 , 1.05
1.16470588 , 1.2
1.26176471 , 1.3
1.35882353 , 1.4
1.45588235 , 1.5
1.55294118 , 1.6
1.65 , 1.7
1.74705882 , 1.8
1.84411765 , 1.9
1.94117647 , 2.0
2.03823529 , 2.1
2.13529412 , 2.2
2.23235294 , 2.3
2.32941176 , 2.4
2.42647059 , 2.5
2.52352941 , 2.6
2.62058824 , 2.7
2.71764706 , 2.8
2.81470588 , 2.9
2.91176471 , 3.0
3.00882353 , 3.1
3.10588235 , 3.2
3.20294118 , 3.3
3.3 , 1.1
```